# Gibt es eine Abkürzung für "letzter Zugriff" oder ähnliches?

Tags: abbreviation, writing

Gibt es eine Abkürzung für "letzter Zugriff am ..." oder für "zuletzt zugegriffen am ..." oder ähnliche Bedeutung?

Ich verwende viel Internetresourcen in meiner Masterarbeit und würde gerne den Phrase abkürzen, da dieser immer wieder unschöne Umbrüche verursacht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drei Vorschläge meinerseits:

- Das englische "ed." für "edition"
- Überleg dir selbst eine Abk. und führe sie im Abkürzungsverzeichnis auf
- Lass es einfach weg.
  Nennung der Quelle mit Datum und Uhrzeit sollte genügen.

Ich würde letzteres bevorzugen. Zumal die Formulierung "**letzter** Zugriff" meiner Meinung nach ohnehin fragwürdig ist. Wie oft du zugegriffen hast, bevor du dich entschieden hast, dich auf den Inhalt zu beziehen, ist doch irrelevant.

Comment: Nebenfrage: braucht es dir Uhrzeit?

Comment: Ich halte diese Antwort größtenteils für ungeeignet. Das *letzte* sagt ja überhaupt nicht aus, *wie oft* man zugegriffen hat, sondern nur, wann das zuletzt (also bei der am wengsten weit zurückliegenden Gelegenheit) erfolgt ist. Und bei "Lass es einfach weg." fehlt die Information ganz. Sinn und Zweck von so etwas ist aber normalerweise, sicherzustellen, dass die Ressourcen zumindest möglichst kurz vor Veröffentlichung der referenzierenden Arbeit noch erreichbarbwaren. *Edition* impliziert wiederum eine Eigenschaft der referenzierten Ressource, was der Zugriff durch den OP ja gerade nicht ist.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper: Nein, Sinn und Zweck ist einzig und allein anzugeben, auf welchen Stand der Website man sich bezieht. Und dazu genügt das Datum i.d.R. voll und ganz. Man muß nicht sicherstellen, daß die Ressource kurz vor Veröffentlichung noch erreichbar ist. Wie soll das praktisch funktionieren? Und wie stellt man sicher, ob dann tatsächlich noch dasselbe drinsteht? Nein, vielmehr ist es ratsam, sich eine Kopie der Seite zu sichern - und zwar just am angegebenen Datum.

Comment: @mic: "@O.R. Mapper: Nein, Sinn und Zweck ist einzig und allein anzugeben, auf welchen Stand der Website man sich bezieht." - interessant, kenne ich (aus den Gelegenheiten, bei denen ich selber solche Arbeiten betreut und mitbetreut habe) anders. Zudem passt das auch nicht ganz damit zusammen, dass ein fürs ganze Literaturverzeichnis gültiger Hinweis à la "Alle Web-Quellen wurden zuletzt am ... besucht." nicht unüblich ist. "Man muß nicht sicherstellen, daß die Ressource kurz vor Veröffentlichung noch erreichbar ist." - doch, genau so kenne ich das. ...

Comment: ... Und das ist ja dann auch eine Aussage zum referenzierten Stand. "Wie soll das praktisch funktionieren?" - ganz einfach, man öffnet am Tag vor dem Druck nochmal alle referenzierten Web-Quellen (was man im Zuge der allgemeinen Sorgfaltspflicht bei seiner Arbeit natürlich sowieso tun sollte) und ändert notfalls etwas ab (aktualisierte URL, Verweis auf die Wayback Machine, Hinweis, dass die URL schon bei Drucklegung unerreichbar war etc.). "Und wie stellt man sicher, ob dann tatsächlich noch dasselbe drinsteht?" - durch Inspizieren des Inhalts. ...

Comment: ... "Nein, vielmehr ist es ratsam, sich eine Kopie der Seite zu sichern - und zwar just am angegebenen Datum." - das kann/sollte man tun, aber für sich genommen hilft das den Lesern des Dokuments eher wenig.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitieren_von_Internetquellen

Comment: Genau deshalb zitiere ich keine Online-Resourcen, sondern verwende solche Seiten nur für weitergehende Informationen und fast ausschliesslich in der Fussnote. Zum Beispiel: Für eine Einführung in Tabu Search vgl. http://home.ifi.uio.no/infheur/Bakgrunn/Intro_to_TS_Gendreau.htm (16. Juli 2016).

Answer (score 7):

Schon an

> (Zugriff: TT.MM.JJJJ)

gedacht?